# Fileupload is not working after downloading file

Tags: c#, file-upload, updatepanel

web-application, c#.NET
I have a multiview in Updatepanel and there are three views.
In third view i am uploading a file and its working.
Then in first view i need to download file.
I achieved it.
I want to add one more AsyncFileUpload Control after Download functionality.
The problem is upload is working but if i first download file and then trying to upload file, its not working(in same view).
Its working if i dont download file and upload but not working if i download and then upload file.
Code to upload file is as follows.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (ext == ".exe" || ext == ".EXE" || ext == ".dll" || ext == ".DLL" || ext == ".config" || ext == ".CONFIG" || ext == ".com" || ext == ".COM")
                {
                    fName = null;
                    lblStatus.Text = "You cant upload " + ext.ToString() + " Files";
                }
                else
                {
                    string newfilename =  e.filename;
                    string strPath = MapPath("../MsgAttach/") + Path.GetFileName(newfilename);
                    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
                }
```

Here is code to download file.

```
string filename = hd_file.Value.ToString();
        string filepath = MapPath("../MsgAttach/" + filename);
        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
                buffer = new byte[fileSize];
                // Read file into buffer
                fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileSize);
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            Response.CacheControl = "public";
            // writes buffer to OutputStream
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Response.End();
        }
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Could you be more precise than "not working"?

Comment: when i first download file and then trying to upload file, the downloaded file will be download again...

Comment: Aside from whatever else is wrong, you're ignoring the result of the call to `FileStream.Read`. You should never *assume* that a call to `Stream.Read` will read all of the data you want in a single call.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? You've only shown *part* of the file upload code path - what happens after that? What is the response?

Comment: its like email facility, when u receive mail, first you check attachment by downloading and then when u want to reply with attach your file. Here the problem is downloading works, uploading works but after downloading the attachment, uploading is not working in reply.

Comment: its not firing event of file upload

Comment: yes, i know about stream.read but i dont know if its creating any problem.

Comment: You still haven't shown what code comes *after* the file upload - is it just falling through into the code which performs the download, for example? A short but *complete* example of this would be really helpful. Also, what happens if you try to upload *without* downloading anything first?

Comment: you cab consider it as a mailing functionality.download and upload are different things here(attach file is optional in functionality), as in email what we are doing is downloading attachment and if we want to reply, we can attach file. Here if i uploadfile without checking attachment, it works. But if i check(download) attachemnt, and then in reply section i am trying to upload file and file_upload event is not firing. I think i am clear now..thnx

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem and looking for him these days I have had some problems, but I hope that someone who is in this same inconvenience this tip you can help:

```
linkMass string = <your new page aspx>;
             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (this.Page, this.GetType (), "script1", "window.open ('" + linkMass +' ',' _self '' directories = no, toolbar = no, scrollbars = no, resizable = no, top = 10, left = 10, width = 200, height = 100 '); ", true);
```

Consider the value '_self' to run on the same page downloading, and have a new aspx code download.

```
Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            Response.CacheControl = "public";
            // writes buffer to OutputStream
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Response.End();
```